# Standard test for the recognition of toroidal graphs

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, algorithms

Is there a standard test for the recognition of toroidal graphs? I have been using the Boyer–Myrvold planarity algorithm, which has a MATLAB and C++ implementation.